# perfmon.exe itself taking 52.71% of CPU on Windows 7 after chrome dies?

Tags: windows-7, performance, perfmon

On my Windows 7 machine (build 7100, x64, Dell XPS M1710 laptop), I'm getting horrible performance after chrome crashes.  I kill the chrome process from the Resource Monitor, but after that perfmon.exe itself is shown as taking about 50% of the CPU (52.31% right now).

Quitting Performance Monitor, then starting it again, shows perfmon starting out with a reasonable CPU, but it quickly (ten seconds) shoots right back up.

Suggestions?  So far a reboot seems to be the only way to solve the problem.  I'm assuming that the perfmon issue is just a symptom of the real problem.

(Update, much later: this never got resolved.  I'm not seeing the problem in the RTM Windows 7 + latest Chrome.  Yes, it was a core 2 duo, so presumably Chrome was running full blast on one CPU.)

Comment: Why do I have the sneaky feeling this is a multi-core machine?  Specifically, one with two cores?  Could you please indicate how many cores you have?

Comment: At the risk that this question may not be revisited - I believe Avery's thought is that on a two processor machine, one processor is at 100% utilization, and the other is idle, reporting 50% utilization.

Answer (score 1):

Perfmon.exe -> try finishing the proces and you will see what happend.
Perfmon = PERF (Performance) MON (Monitor)
Actually the logic name for the Resource Monitor process it could be "Resmon"... but we know microsoft.

Un saludo! I hope that this helps you.